# how to push an object like this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, gantt-chart

may I know how to push `var obj= [{}]` in `.each`? for example like this.

```
 $.each(maintasks_row, function(index, maintasks_val) { 
                obj.push([{
                    "name" : maintasks_val.task_name,
                    "desc" : "",
                    "values" : [{
                        "from" : "/Date("+maintasks_val.time_start+")/",
                        "to" : "/Date("+maintasks_val.time_end+")/",
                        "label": maintasks_val.task_name,
                        "customClass" : "ganttRed"
                    }]
                }]);
            });
```

I'm using this for `$(".gantt").gantt({source: obj});`

On [this site](http://mbielanczuk.com/jquery-gantt/) the `var data` is `[{}]` is this an object? and how can I insert it?

thank you

Comment: You're adding single-element arrays comprising an object onto `obj` here; is that what you want?

Comment: You said you want to push object but inserting array of object, what you want to do?

Comment: yes, i want to insert it like this `var data = [
{ "name": " Step A ","desc": "&rarr; Step B"  ,"values": [{"id": "b0", "from": "/Date(1320182000000)/", "to": "/Date(1320301600000)/", "desc": "Id: 0<br/>Name:   Step A", "label": " Step A", "customClass": "ganttRed", "dep": "b1"}]
}];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.push` does not require you delcare it as an array ( like you tried `obj.push([{` - unless of course you are pushing an array into an array

Just simply ...

```
obj.push({"name" : maintasks_val.task_name, ..
```

adds a new single item intto the array

---

*Update as comment ,* yes, declare `obj` as a `typeof` array first

```
var obj=[];
```

This is now the same as the `data` array you have shown in your [docs example](http://mbielanczuk.com/jquery-gantt/) - and we can now `.push()` into it.

Comment: I tried that sir but it doesn't work 
`$.each(maintasks_row, function(index, maintasks_val) { 
        obj.push({
         "name" : maintasks_val.task_name,
        });
    });`

I have a `var obj = {}` at top

Comment: guess I got the error, I change `var obj = {}` to `var obj = []` thanks alot sir